# UK standard visitor visa application for plab/ british spouse

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, pakistani-citizens, spouses

I'm a doctor from Pakistan. My husband is a British citizen and we have a one-year-old daughter, whose passport we have just applied for.

My husband is unemployed, so we do not meet the income requirement for a spouse visa. However, Ineed to apply for a standard visitor visa to take my plab 2 exam.

I am afraid my application would be rejected due to insufficient ties to my home country. I've been employed in the same job for 3 years, however I do not own any land or even have a rental agreement in my name. I live with my in-laws and they pay for the utilities etc.

What other documents could I attach to strengthen my case? And secondly I haven't decided whether to take my daughter along or not. If her passport arrives in time I could take her with me. What bearing would that have on my case?

I intend to apply for 5 days. The other option is to apply for 5 weeks and attend the short academy course most people take before the exam, but I pessimistically think that would completely ruin any chance I have of being granted a visa...

Comment: How much do you plan to spend on your trip and is this a reasonable amount given your monthly income and general financial situation? Can you show savings in your home country and is it feasible to leave your daughter in the care of relatives during your visit (it’s not clear from your question where your husband resides)? A stable job, family ties and savings should be a reasonable premise for a short visit application.

Comment: The fact that you are applying to take a recognised test (and optionally a related course) is very strong, as is the fact you have a job. Hopefully this outweighs not having property.

Comment: @user16259 If she didn't had an husband who is a British citizen, that would have been enough. Considering her husband is a citizen, that muddies up the situation quite strongly. The officer would find that as a very big motive to not return.

Comment: @dumbcoder I agree. I hope Sabin17 and the home office take the economically rational view that it is better to work as a licenced doctor anywhere than to live illegally in the UK, unable to practice your profession.

Comment: @Traveller i have put some thought into the finances and yes i could show savings. Its the family ties that has me worried since my husband resides in the Uk.

Comment: @user16259 i hope so too. Ive invested a lot of time and effort in these liscensing exams.

Comment: Also, anyone visiting to take plab must be intending to work in the UK and so inevitably have weaker ties to home. I would expect the home office to factor this in. I imagine you should include evidence of your exam booking.

Comment: @dumbcoder Assuming the OP intends to stay with her family in the UK does the husband being unemployed muddy the water even further? That is, could the ECO take the view that the OP would indirectly have recourse to public funds ie via any benefits the husband is receiving?

Comment: @Traveller i dnt intend to stay at my husbands house. Since the exam is only held in manchester... but that is also what i am concerned about.